# How do I update an object at a single location without overriding other fields using Firebase's Java Admin SDK?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

```
Users
    |_ randomPushKey
        |_ firstName: "John"
        |_ LastName: "Doe"
        |_ eyeColor: "Brown"
        |_ age: 24
```

*figure 1*

Using the Firebase Admin SDK I want to update the above User such that the end result is as follows:

```
Users
    |_ randomPushKey
        |_ firstName: "John"
        |_ LastName: "Doe"
        |_ eyeColor: "Black"
        |_ age: 25
```

*figure 2*

I failed to find any method that updates data at a specific location (without removing values that are not sent in the request), which in this case would be `randomPushKey`.

The closest method I could find was `databaseReference.updateChildren();`, **however** that method accepts a `Map<String, Object>` and **not** a single `Object`, which is the objective in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will still want to use `updateChildren`.  Just pass it the paths of **only** the fields you want to modify, relative to the reference that you're using.  This is called a multi-location update, as generally described [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html).

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("eyeColor", ...);
map.put("age", ...);
DatabaseRereference ref = ...; // This should point to Users/randomPushKey
databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
```